# Determine if a subset of the faces of a doubly connected edge list (DCEL) forms a simply connected region

Tags: graph-theory, computational-geometry

I'm trying to make my toy implementation of the incremental convex hull algorithm a bit more robust, and in certain degenerate cases, with many almost coplanar points, the visible region contains 'holes'.

Is there any way to check if the faces marked visible form a simply connected region?

I was thinking of some sort of BFS, given a certain starting point, but I can't quite get a hold of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have easy ways to traverse your mesh.  If not, then another algorithm might be more suitable.

Keep a set of edge indices that are border edges.

- Iterate through every face in the selection.
- For each face, look at all it's edges.
- If the face on the other side of the edge is also a selected face, then continue to the next edge on the face.
- Otherwise, the edge is a border edge.

  - Do a floodfill along the border for border edges.  This will either form a complete loop, or go off the edge of the mesh.
  - If it goes off the edge of the mesh then you'll need to keep searching along the border of the mesh until you hit an edge that is a border of the selection, and follow up through there, until you are able to form a complete loop.
  - Add that loop to the set of border edges for quick lookup.

As you continue looping through all faces' edges looking for border edges, check each border edge against the set of border edges you got from your first loop.  If the new border edge is not in the set of border edges then it forms a second loop, meaning that your selection isn't compact.